# Iterate in compact json structure using jquery

Tags: javascript, json, loops

Is there easy way to iterate json structure like this ?

```
var xstring = [ {"test1",1} ,{"test2",2} ,{"test77","aa"} ] ;
```

Comment: That's an invalid data structure. The stuff between `{` and `}` should be a dictionary, which needs key/value pairs. That JavaScript shouldn't even run. Exactly what are you trying to represent? And what do you want to achieve by "iterating" over it?

Comment: Thank you i see now that is bad idea :). I was thinking about converting string to json to minimize data size but its not worth this.

Comment: If you are talking about json structures, there's no need for the `var xstring =` because that makes it JavaScript Code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Samir Talwar is right, the data inside the curly brackets is a dictionary so instead you'll have something like this.

```
var xstring = [ {"test1": 1}, {"tests2": 2}, {"test3": "aa"} ];
```

But then, it doesn't really make much sense to have different dictionaries, with only one key, maybe what you are looking for is just a dictionary (object), like this.

```
var xstring = { "test1": 1, "test2": 2, "test3": "aa" };
```

So xstring is a dictionary/object type, there's not really an iterator object in javascript, but you could just go through the items, using a `for` loop.

```
for(var property in xstring){
  xstring[property]; // Here are your values: 1, 2, "aa"
}
```